# Sqlite app not working on my device, but does on my emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

In my app I have used Sqlite. When I test the app in the emulator it runs ok but when I test the app on my device, it fails because the Helper class not pass by the OnCreate method. My java code is below.

```
public static void startDB(Context context) {

    DBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    } 

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(USER_CREATE);
    } 

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        for (String table : ALL_TABLES) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table);
        }
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has the application run before on the device (could it be that there is an old DB in the device)?

Comment: adb uninstall <yourpackagename>

Comment: Try what laalto suggests or alternatively increment your database version number. That will trigger onUpgrade which in turn will call onCreate (as per your code).

Answer (score 1):

The framework only calls `onCreate()` if the database does not exist.

To force `onCreate()`, remove the old database file: clear your app's data in app manager, or just uninstall and reinstall.